# Make valid and working url from string, php

Tags: php, url, urlencode, str-replace

I have a problem with producing  valid urls from strings. E.g.:

```
"http://mysite.de/go/".$text
```

I want to add text, might be a title, to the link. The script behind go/ takes the title, gets the ID of the post, uses the ID to get an url from the database to execute it. This works for e.g.

```
$text = "zalando.de"
```

But for

```
$text = "1&1 Email"
```

it does not work. S I think I have to encode $text to make it valid?
Is there a standart method to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) to encode the string properly:

```
"http://mysite.de/go/".rawurlencode($text)
```